# Issue with docker not acknowledging docker-compose.override.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm particularly new to Docker. I was trying to containerize a project for development and production versions. I came up with a very basic docker-compose configuration and then tried the override feature which doesn't seem to work.

I added overrides for volumes to *web* and *celery* services which do not actually mount to the container, can confirm the same by looking at the inspect log of both the containers.

Contents of compose files:-

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    depends_on:
      - redis


  redis:
    image: redis:5.0.9-alpine

  celery:
    build: .
    command: celery worker -A facedetect.celeryapp -l INFO --concurrency=1 --without-gossip --without-heartbeat
    depends_on:
      - redis
    environment:
      - C_FORCE_ROOT=true
```

**docker-compose.override.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

  celery:
    volumes:
      - .:/code
```

I use Docker with Pycharm on Windows 10.

Command executed to deploy the compose configuration:-
`C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-compose.exe" -f <full-path>/docker-compose.yml up -d`

Command executed to inspect one of the containers:-
`docker container inspect <container_id>`

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Add to the question the commands you run the app and the commands you use to check for the volume not being present.

Comment: just updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out that I had provided the docker-compose.yml file explicitly to the Run Configuration created in Pycharm as it was mandatory to provide at least one of these.

The command used by Pycharm explicitly mentions the .yml files using -f option when running the configuration. Adding the *docker-compose.override.yml* file to the Run Configuration changed the command to
`C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-compose.exe" -f <full_path>\docker-compose.yml -f <full_path>/docker-compose.override.yml up -d`

This solved the issue. Thanks to Exadra37 directing to look out for the command that was being executed.